# Do the F-18's leading edge flaps deflect symmetrically in rolls?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing, fa-18

When the F-18 Hornet does rolls, do the Leading Edge Flaps (LEFs) deflect symmetrically or is the deflection different on the left and right LEFs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting the F/A-18A,B,C,D Flight Manual A1-F18AC-NFM-000, I-2-42

> **2.8.2.8 Control Augmentation System (CAS)** [...] The lateral control system uses ailerons, **differential
>   trailing edge flaps, differential leading
>   edge flaps, differential stabilator, and rudders** to
>   achieve the desired roll characteristics. Scheduled
>   air data roll rate feedback is used to augment
>   inherent airframe roll damping. At high
>   airspeeds, aileron travel versus stick movement
>   is reduced and the ailerons do not deflect above
>   600 knots. Differential stabilator and differential
>   trailing edge flap travel is reduced at high speed
>   to prevent exceeding structural limits. The leading
>   edge flaps deflect differentially up to ± 3°
>   when below 30,000 feet and above 0.7 MACH. Differential flaps are not used in the takeoff or land modes nor above 10° AOA in the auto flaps
>   up mode. At low airspeeds, aileron and differential
>   stabilator travel are reduced with increasing
>   AOA to minimize adverse yaw.

In short: Yes the F18 uses differential (asymmetric) deflections on the leading edge flaps and trailing edge flaps but the scheduling depends on angle of attack, airspeed and Mach number.

Comment: Hard to emulate that in my sim